# Persistent in-memory concurrent dictionary in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In an ASP.NET Core application, I would like to have persistent, shared state that is analogous to:

```cs
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job> Jobs;
```

Various components of the applications will access this shared state (request handling controllers, background tasks), but my main concern isn't concurrent access. What I'm curious about is whether there is a way to persist a global variable like this throughout the lifetime of my ASP.NET Core application.

Is there a place I can define this global `Jobs` variable where it will not be destroyed by the ASP.NET Core runtime? Perhaps leveraging `MemoryCache` in some way?

Using something like Redis would certainly work, but I'm curious if there is a robust in-memory/in-process solution for global shared state in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Seems you answered your own question by suggesting the `MemoryCache`, if you need some documentation on using it in .Net Core this should help (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: My main concern with `MemoryCache` is this line from the documentation you linked: "Apps should be written and tested to never depend on cached data.".

In my case, I want the `MemoryCache` to be the source of truth for the shared state. I'm not sure if that's what `MemoryCache` is designed for.

Comment: Maybe you could just create a service wrapper for it and set it as a singleton in the startup.

Comment: Seems your concern is durability, therefore you should consider using a distributed cache like Redis.

Comment: If you want the data to be persistent, use a database, not an in-memory variable.  Variables aren't the place for persisting data for your application.  Caches are designed to be both temporary and re-creatable.  If that's not true of your data, you shouldn't be using a cache.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like Redis would be a good fit for this application.

Answer (score 14):

You can wrap `ConcurrentDictionary` within a class and register it as singleton.

```
public class SharedJobs
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job> _jobs
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job>();

    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job> Jobs => _jobs;
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<SharedJobs>();
```

Usage

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly SharedJobs _shared;

    public Service(SharedJobs shared) => _shared = shared;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var job = _shared.Jobs.GetOrAdd("Key", new Job("New Job when not found"));
    }
}
```

You can go further and hide the fact that you are using `ConcurrentDictionary` under the hood and expose only required functionality to the consumers.

```
public class SharedJobs
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job> _jobs
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job>();

    public Job Get(string key)
    {
        return _jobs.GetOrAdd(key, CreateNewJob());
    }

    private Job CreateNewJob() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a persistent layer on top of `IMemoryCache` by using [AcroFS](https://github.com/ghominejad/AcroFS#persistent-cache-quick-examples-) tiny library. It will try to load data from memory first, then tries to load from disk.

If you have various projects in different locations you can set an absolute path for the cache folder.

```cs
// set cache
_memoryCache.Persistent().Set(key, jobs);

// get cache
var found = _memoryCache.Persistent().TryGetValue(cacheKey, out jobs);

// get or create
var jobs = await _memoryCache.Persistent().GetOrCreate(cacheKey, async entry => await loadJobsAsync());
```

Answer (score -1):

Ask for a `IMemoryCache` in your controller's / service's constructor.

First add to your startup to register the cache services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

...ask for it in a constructor...

```
private IMemoryCache _cache;

public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _cache = memoryCache;
}
```

...and use it...

```
public IActionResult CacheTryGetValueSet()
{
    DateTime cacheEntry;

    // Look for cache key.
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.Entry, out cacheEntry))
    {
        // Key not in cache, so get data.
        cacheEntry = DateTime.Now;

        // Set cache options.
        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            // Keep in cache for this time, reset time if accessed.
            .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        // Save data in cache.
        _cache.Set(CacheKeys.Entry, cacheEntry, cacheEntryOptions);
    }

    return View("Cache", cacheEntry);
}
```

Read Microsoft's [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for more details. All of the above code comes from that page.

The memory cache provided here is a Singleton - a single instance of the cache will exist for the entire duration of the application. Be mindful though, as soon as the process shuts down, everything is cleared.

---

As for the concern "well what if my cache doesn't have the value at the moment I ask for it?"

Uh, welcome to multi-threaded code. This is just fact of life, cache-misses are a thing. It's going to be """"more""" reliable because the whole cycle is in memory, but you still need to take it into consideration.

Comment: As mentioned above, my main concern with MemoryCache is this line from the documentation you linked: "Apps should be written and tested to never depend on cached data.". In my case, I want the MemoryCache to be the source of truth for the shared state. There is no database backing the in-memory data. I'm not sure if `MemoryCache` is really designed for this.

Comment: If you're worried about the data being deleted after you set it - that's not a problem. If you're worried about race conditions due to this being multithreaded, that might be a problem (then again, that's an issue with all caching).

Comment: This won't do what the OP wants. Concurrent protection is provided by an in-memory dictionary but the memory cache is just an object store, if two threads end up creating their own concurrent dictionary from the same object cache, then there is no concurrency protection and one could easily overwrite the other in cache. The correct way is to inject a singleton.