# Two Worker Service, one for write operation another for read operation .Net core worker services

Tags: c#, .net-core, backgroundworker

**The .Net core Worker service  templete as shown below**

```
  public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {            
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                 await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is .net core worker service code .It loops to write log every 10000 ms .
My Question: After every 10000 ms, How to call another worker service using this worker service.

Comment: What is your logging provider? We can't really tell from the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to call another worker service using this worker service.

My first question would be "why do you want to do this?" This is *extremely* unusual.

But if you really want to, then you could add an in-memory queue (e.g., `Channel<T>`) wrapper as a singleton and inject it into both workers. Then one worker could consume the channel and the other worker could produce into it.

Comment: First worker will insert data into database on every 10000 ms and second worker will read inserted data whose inserted that 10000 ms.

Comment: @Subrato: If the second worker is polling the db, then why send a message from the first to the second?

Comment: if i do not send message from first worker to second worker then how to  read current 10000ms inserted data .

Comment: Let me put it another way: why have two workers instead of one?

Comment: *"My first question would be 'why do you want to do this?' This is extremely unusual."* In my case, I have some data in my database, which can be updated while I'm working on it. One of my workers retrieves data from the database, writes it to a ConcurrentDictionary, and continually checks for the update. Other worker uses this dictionary repeatedly and does their job and doesn't bother with all the data retrieve & update operations. You can check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55802787/6130594) to see how Stephen's answer can be applied.